# How can I use Tor as a proxy for another browser?

Tags: browsers, chrome, safari

I know you're not supposed to do this if you want maximum security, but the Tor Browser is not rendering a page (probably broken HTML), and I'd like to use Chrome or Safari to render the page.  I see some pages online saying you can point your browser's proxy settings at 127.0.0.1 and various ports, but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using linux, you can start another browser with Tor by
   using command: `torify iceweasel`
2. In firefox you can of course set your proxy to a Tor proxy. Just insert `192.168.2.1:9150`

Answer (score 1):

See, there is such options in config file of Tor, `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
SocksPort 9050
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
```

You could find the same in your `torrc`, uncomment it and launch your browser with "Proxy settings",  `proxy type: socks5`, `address: 127.0.0.1`, `port 9050`.